# How do I create a PR trigger on Azure Dev Ops with multiple build validations and path filters?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This will build successfully after I have completed a PR, but it's not building as part of the validation of the PR. Also, for some reason when I create a new release from the dev branch, it's not triggering a build there either (and thus one of the conditions I have where it builds on a release branch, it's not creating the artifact for my release pipeline).

The current build validation I have for my branch policy on both Dev and my Releases/* branch

[image: Build Validation]

My Azure Pipeline for the API:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - Dev
    - Releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - MCR.API/*

jobs:
- job: api
  variables:
    configuration: release
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps: 
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**/*API.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      command: build
      projects: '**/*API.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish API
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/*API.csproj'
      arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --configuration $(configuration)'
      zipAfterPublish: True

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish API Artifact'
    condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Releases/'))
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      artifactName: 'API'
```

I am wanting this to force a PR to dev and Releases/* to have a successful build before it can be completed (it's not doing that). I want it to build after the PR is completed (it IS doing that). I want it to build when a new Release in the Releases/* branch is created (it's not doing that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this problem was rather simple...

In the build validation policy, make sure you have a leading slash in front of your directory - even though you don't need one in your yaml pipelines file.

So far example I changed this:

```
MCR.API/*
MCR/*
MCR.Admin/*
```

To:

```
/MCR.API/*
/MCR/*
/MCR.Admin/*
```

And everything worked as I wanted.

Comment: but `/MCR/*` includes all the others?

Comment: The folder structure of this project is a little weird... the physical folders for the projects are named MCR.API, MCR.Admin, and then one just called MCR (which is the UI and should have been named MCR.UI but I digress).

So /MCR/* is just triggered off changes to the UI project - it doesn't include everything..

Comment: Hi codeMetis, thanks for your sharing and please [accept it as self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)